# Запятые в предложении "Возможность наблюдать(,) что происходит на улице(,) благодаря нашей камере слежения"

Tags: пунктуация

> Возможность наблюдать(,) что происходит на улице(,) благодаря нашей камере слежения.

Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере запятые открывают и закрывают придаточное предложение.

Comment: То я и подозревал. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что в таком виде предложение можно считать корректным. Оборот "благодаря чему-то" требует глагола, а его тут нет.  Варианты исправления:

**Благодаря нашей камере слежения есть (появилась) возможность наблюдать, что происходит на улице.**

**Возможность наблюдать, что происходит на улице, появившаяся благодаря нашей камере слежения.**

**Возможность наблюдать, что происходит на улице, с помощью нашей камеры слежения**

**Наша камера слежения дает возможность наблюдать, что происходит на улице.**

Оборот "благодаря чему-то" не обособляется.

> [БЛАГОДАРЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), предлог. кому-чему. Из-за кого-, чего-л., по причине, вследствие чего-л. (обычно при указании на положительный, желаемый результат). Б. ветерку не так уж и жарко. Спасся б. друзьям. Б. отцу знаю иностранные языки. <Благодаря тому что, союз. По причине того что, вследствие того что. Образован благодаря тому, что много читал.